# How do I store variables in a file so that they keep their values where I can print them out in the program?

Tags: python

I'm wanting to store values in a file so that they maintain their properties. Please see a snippet of my code below.

```
        if selection == ("1"):
            newUserID = input ("Please enter their 3 digit ID: ")
            #check the user has put in numbers and at least 3 digits
            newUserName = input("Please enter the employees name: ")
            #check for string not number. Has to be exactly their name
            newUserPassword = input ("Please enter their Clocking in password: ")
            count = count + 1
            uniqueUserID = (newUserID, newUserName, newUserPassword, count)
            uniqueUserID = str(uniqueUserID)
            file.write(uniqueUserID)
            file.close()
```

I'm using Python and also need to make it so that the user's inputs are stored in a "count" variable to keep track of how many users there are.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to start looking into using a database

Comment: How exactly would I do this with python? Sorry - I'm fairly new to coding.

Comment: You can use a local SQLite database. You would be able to create a table, called users for example, with the id, username, and password as fields. As an introduction, I'd recommend reading this article: https://datatofish.com/create-database-python-using-sqlite3/

Comment: Would I be able to use microsoft access for this?

Comment: Yes, that would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Put them values in a dict like below and then write the dictionary as json in the file.

```
dict = {}
dict['newUserID'] = newUserID
dict['newUserName'] = newUserName
dict['newUserPassword'] = newUserPassword
dict['count'] = count
with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(dict, fp)
```

This assumes `import json`

Comment: Does this store values the user puts in as multiple variables?